# React updating props when I update the state that references to that props

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have a component which has an array props, and inside that component, I destructure that props to a useState. For example

```
function Field({myArray}) {
    const [tempArray, setTempArray] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        let temp = [...myArray];
        setTempArray(temp);
    }, [myArray])

}
```

Now, I have a function that updates the `tempArray` by `setTempArray(someArray)`, now, when it updates, the `myArray` props also updates, why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use deep copy
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Deep_copy

because a deep copy shares no references with its source object, any changes made to the deep copy do not affect the source object

```js
function Field({ myArray }) {
  const [tempArray, setTempArray] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myArray));
    setTempArray(temp);
  }, [myArray])

}
```